# How to send email notification on the basis of different job

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have job A which trigger build on the basis of commit, after completion of job A, job B will get triggered as downstream job.

IN my case both job A and B send email notification.

How can i configure like job A trigger job B so that after successful completion of job B , i wanted to send email notification to the committer of job A aswellas global recipient.

Can any one help me regarding this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Try the [Blame Upstream Committers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin) plugin.

**2.** If you trigger Job-B via "trigger parameterized build" from Job-A, then you can pass any information from Job-A to Job-B.

(for that one, I am not sure how the committer is saved - 
please advise the plugin you use and if the committer is listed as an environment variable of some sort).

Comment: I am not using parameterized plugin, but just giving build one project after another. So completion of job A will go to job B. I am using email-ext plugin for notification. I need to know about some fingerprinting which will share info between jobs. But i am not getting how to implement this?

Comment: It should work even with the simpler triggering of jobs - please read the explanation in the plugin I have mentioned above.